# Tick To... what does tock look like?

Tags: mathematics, english

If **tick** looks like this:

[image: tick]

> What does **tock** look like?

Hint:

> Its to  do with the angles

Hint 2:

> Don't lose your **bearings**

Hint 3:

> Try multiplication

Comment: Is it related to English shorthand notation? Or does have to do with lines and angles given??

Comment: @ABcDexter based on the math tag alone I'd go for the latter - perhaps some kind of tutrle-based movement from the letters?

Comment: @ABcDexter I'll give a hint. Its to do with the angles

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with the position of the letter in the alphabet, which throuhg some gymnastics dictates what angle is used for the line

Comment: @Xylius you are on to something there

Comment: Is the drawing to scale?

Comment: @Xylius it doesn't actually matter about the length of the lines

Comment: Sorry, I meant the angles

Comment: I've been going at this for 2 days now and I can't think of anything else I could do with numbers considering you said that I didn't need anything other than the letters provided

Comment: I second @xyilus question.  Are the angles to scale?  I particularly take question to the one on the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tock Looks like this

> [image]

Bearings:

> Absolute bearings are measured from 0 as North all the way around to 360 in a clockwise direction.

tick corresponds to the letters

> t = 20
>  i = 9
>  c = 3
>  k = 11
>  The four bearings for the lines are calculated by multiplying the values of the adjacent letters.
>  ti = 180
>  ic = 27
>  ck = 33
>  kt = 220

Therefore tock is:

> t = 20
>  o = 15
>  c = 3
>  k = 11
>  The four bearings for the lines are calculated by multiplying the values of the adjacent letters.
>  to = 300
>  oc = 45
>  ck = 33
>  kt = 220

Comment: Well done, you have got it bang on

Answer (score 6):

I think I have it

> The diagram's angles are bearing that are calculated dividing 360
>  degrees by the position of the letter in the alphabet:
>  T: 360/20=18
>  I: 360/9=40
>  C: 360/3=120
>  Not sure what to do with the K
>
>  The angles produce a diagram like this:
>  [image]
>  Using the same logic for Tock:
>  T: 360/20=18
>  O: 360/15=24
>  C: 360/3=120
>  Again I can't find a function for the K
>
>  Hence "Tock" looks like this:
>  [image]

Comment: I have added another hint, i'm afraid those are the wrong type of angles

Comment: Sorry about the spoiler tag blunder :s

Comment: Close but no cigar, the only numbers you need to calculate the bearings are the letters in the alphabet, not 360

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil OK, but what a coincidence, though.